# Do I have to reboot between flashing ROM, root and Xposed?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, xposed-framework, magisk

I am going to flash a custom ROM, systemless root (Magisk) and Xposed Framwork through TWRP.

Can I flash them all sequentially without rebooting, or do I have to reboot the phone between each installation?

My device is the Moto Z2 Play and my ROM is the Pixel Experience 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can flash the custom Rom and Magisk without rebooting. However, I would reboot after flashing the custom Rom and Magisk. That way you can ensure your system and root are setup. Xposed is a bit hacking and it is best to flash on its own.

As far as Xposed you **very important to reboot** after flashing xposed. Also depending on Rom size it could take around 10 minutes to boot while Xposed does its thing.

Comment: I'd just like to add that it's recommended to da a reboot after every flash. regardless of the modifications it makes to your device. Also Xposed isn't that much hacking, it just replaces two or three files on your system with vulnerable ones and then exploits that vulnerability. It's annoying to remove completely because most people dont know what it's done.... `/system/bin/app_process` is the file that sticks around after removing...  it makes your device vulnerable and should be replaced with the .bakup file that xposed made... New Super User programs do the same.

Comment: +1.Fully agree about reboot after flashing Xposed. IMO, it is better to reboot if you are doing any changes ; makes it easier to debug problems

Comment: Interesting, I guess it depends on the situation. Like sure after a freshly compiled ROM I reboot after every flash for debugging purposes to see what broke and needed to be fixed. As just a user I was taught you flash rom and gaps reboot recovery kernel, root, and whatever binaries mods reboot system set up OS and move files if needed reboot recovery then rm -rf /data/dalvik-cache. I have to disagree with rebooting after every single .extension is flashed for the average user but it okay. Everybody got their procedure 0_o @beeshyams♦ @Zillinium